# Markers opacity in StyledMarker with google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) library to dynamically generate my markers because the [dynamic icons](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons) are deprecated. Now, in this API there is not the possibility to set the markers opacity..and this is crucial for my application. Currently I am loading the markers in this way:

```
var marker = new StyledMarker({
    styleIcon:new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.MARKER,
                            {color:generateColor()}),
    position:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),map:map});
```

I have not been able to find a solution and I think that I will have to switch to statically generated markers instead .. :(

Comment: Did you know that this library also uses the deprecated dynamic chart-icons?

Comment: I realised that...but there must be a reason why the cart icons are deprecated...isn't there?

Comment: Ok, there is no way to dynamically generate what I want using official tools. I am gonna have to deal with it..
I have been looking so many websites and they all say "edit your png locally and host it in the webserver"..